# Empty API Response When Deleting Payment Method ID In Shopware 6 Administration

Tags: vue.js, shopware6, shopware6-api

When I try deleting the `paymentMethodId` from `sales_channel_payment_method` table I get an empty response from the API and the payload object `DELETE http://localhost/api/sales-channel-payment-method/[object Object]` seems empty too.

Below is my Vue js method

```js
const { Component} = Shopware;

import template from './pau-settings-page.html.twig';

Component.register('pau-settings-page', {

   template,

   inject: [
    'repositoryFactory'
    ],

   metaInfo() {
      return {
          title: this.$createTitle()
      };
    },

 

   computed: {

    salesChannelPaymentMethodRepository() {
        return this.repositoryFactory.create('sales_channel_payment_method');
    },



    
   },


   methods: {



    deletePaymentMethodIdHeadless(){

       const identity = { 
                            fieldCount: 2, 
                            fieldsString: "05cde2abfe744bffaf47ad71f8a49270, f6dd50230aa145adb6b73801d4bcf31b",
                            fields: ['salesChannelId', 'paymentMethodId'] 
                        };


        this.salesChannelPaymentMethodRepository.delete(
            identity, Shopware.Context.api
        );

       

    },

    

   }

    
  
});
```

[Image of The Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxZw6.png)

Comment: This fragment of code seems to not be connected with described problem. Please describe it more preciselly, eg why you have [object Object] in url, and add better code fragments, eg body of salesChannelPaymentMethodRepository method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to remove a many-to-many mapping. These feature two distinct primary keys, both foreign keys of the related tables. You already have the right idea. The regular delete endpoint only works with single primary keys, hence why you get the malformed url.

To delete the mappings you may use the `syncService` instead.

```js
const { Component} = Shopware;

import template from './pau-settings-page.html.twig';

Component.register('pau-settings-page', {
    template,
    inject: [
        'repositoryFactory',
        'syncService',
    ],
    metaInfo() {
        return {
            title: this.$createTitle()
        };
    },
    computed: {
        salesChannelPaymentMethodRepository() {
            return this.repositoryFactory.create('sales_channel_payment_method');
        },
    },
    methods: {
        deletePaymentMethodIdHeadless() {
            const payload = [{
                action: 'delete',
                entity: 'sales_channel_payment_method',
                payload: [
                    {
                        salesChannelId: '05cde2abfe744bffaf47ad71f8a49270',
                        paymentMethodId: 'f6dd50230aa145adb6b73801d4bcf31b'
                    },
                ],
            }];

            this.syncService.sync(payload, {}, { 'single-operation': 1 });
        },
    },
});
```

Comment: I have updated my question with an image of the response. You can see the image here too [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxZw6.png)

Comment: Ah, I see. I missed the part about the malformed url and thought it was only about the response. I updated my answer.

Comment: Do you mind if I ask for more clarifications here?

Comment: There's really not that much to explain. Earlier you were using an API endpoint that expects a string as an argument, but you passed an object. Hence the malformed url when that got stringified. The sync api is an alternative way of doing CRUD operations with the API and allows you to pass objects, which is necessary for deleting mapping entities. You can find a [basic description of the sync API here](https://shopware.stoplight.io/docs/admin-api/b3A6MTMzMTcwODg-bulk-edit-entities).

Comment: Will it affect other tables other than the `sales_channel_payment_method` table?

Comment: No, this will only delete the mapping.